# How can active accordion tab on click

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery

I want to active an accordion tab on button click with activate() method https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_tabs.html#fedg_tabs_methods-activate

This is my test code

```
<div id="element">
        <div class="custom_collapsible">
            <div class="custom_trigger">
                <span>Title 1</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="custom_content">Content 1</div>

        <div class="custom_collapsible">
            <div class="custom_trigger">
                <span>Title 2</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="custom_content">Content 2</div>

        <div class="custom_collapsible">
            <div class="custom_trigger">
                <span>Title 3</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="custom_content">Content 3</div>
    </div>

    <button id="btn">Activate 1</button>
    <script>

        if (2 == 2) {
            var collapsible = true
        } else {
            var collapsible = false
        }

        require([
            'jquery',
            'accordion'], function ($) {
            $('#btn').click(function() {
                $("#element").accordion().activate(2);
            });
            $("#element").accordion({
                active: [0,1],
                closedState: "accordion-closed",
                collapsible : collapsible, 
                collapsibleElement : ".custom_collapsible", 
                content : ".custom_content",
                disabled : [2],
                disabledState : "accordion-disabled",
                trigger : ".custom_trigger",
                icons: {"header": "plus", "activeHeader": "minus" }

            });
        });
    </script>
```

but i get this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).accordion(...).activate is not a function
```

what i'm wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is right way

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
    $("#element").accordion("activate", [1]);
});
```

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_accordion.html#meth_act

Answer (score 0):

Give your trigger a unique class or id e.g

```
<div class="custom_collapsible">
        <div class="custom_trigger unique-class">
            <span>Title 1</span>
        </div>
</div>
```

then in the script, you can click the trigger

```
$('.unique-class').click();
```